# How to create an array or group of Directives in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I currently have a module with a Component and a Directive which supports the Component in my Angular 2 app. For the user to use this Component they have to import both the Component and the Directive. Is there a way that I can group them into something like `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`

For eg:

```
import {Component, HostListener, Directive} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-dropdown",
    templateUrl: "./dropdown.html",
    styleUrls: ["./dropdown.css"]
})
export class Dropdown {
    //code
}

@Directive({
    selector: ".my-dropdown-toggle"
})
export class DropdownToggle{

    //code
}
```

To use this the user has to import like this:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    directives: [Dropdown,DropdownToggle,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: "./dropdown-sample.html"
})
export class DropdownAngularDemo {
}
```

I want to know if I can group `Dropdown` and `DropdownToggle` into an array like `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ROUTER_PROVIDERS`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d272f96e23f379e1b565435b3af010138e710ab9/modules/angular2/src/router/router_providers.ts#L31) is delcared as

```ts
export const ROUTER_PROVIDERS: any[] = CONST_EXPR([
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS_COMMON,
  CONST_EXPR(new Provider(PlatformLocation, {useClass: BrowserPlatformLocation})),
]);
```

you can do the same with your own directives

```ts
export const DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES: any[] = CONST_EXPR([
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle
]);
```

and use it like

```ts
import {DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES} from 'somedir/somefile';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    directives: [DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: "./dropdown-sample.html"
})
export class DropdownAngularDemo {
}
```

You can also create groups of groups of directives (or providers). Angular expands nested arrays itself (no need to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)).

```ts
export const MY_DIRECTIVES: any[] = CONST_EXPR([
  DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
  ModalDialog,
  MainMenu
]);
```

Comment: Thanks! For other users just so that they don't have to find this:
CONST_EXPR is imported from here: `import {CONST_EXPR} from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to import your directives and export the constant that groups the directives:

```ts
import {Dropdown, DropdownToggle} from 'dropdow.component';

export const DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES: any[] = [Dropdown, DropdownToggle]
```

to use:

```ts
import {DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES} from 'dir/file';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    directives: [DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: "./app.html"
})
export class AppComponent{
  //code
}
```